# Can I determine 'not 100% charged' using AE2 fuzzy logic upgrades in export buses?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-applied-energistics

I'm trying to automate the charging of all my gear, because it's getting tiring to toss each thing into a different MFE/MFSU, wait for it to charge, then remember to pick it up.

I know that a charging station exists as an add-on for IndustrialCraft 2 experimental, but I'd rather build my own, and I don't know if it has even been ported to 1.7.2 / 1.7.10. So, I did some experimenting, and I determined that I can automate this to some extent. I set up an ad-hoc network using an ME chest, and some import / export buses:

[image]

Basically, I can toss any *completely* depleted item into the ME chest, it gets picked up by export buses, placed in one of the MFSUs, where an import bus programmed to pull the item once 100% charged places it back into the ME chest. This works perfectly, I can toss stuff in the chest, go do other things, then come back to find my gear fully charged.

However, it *only* works if the gear is completely out of power. I've tried several configurations with fuzzy logic upgrades in the export buses (which put the items into the MFSUs), so that any item with only a partial charge gets picked up, but I'm not having a lot of luck. They're not getting picked up.

What I did was, took one of each item at 50% charge, told the fuzzy logic card to split the damage at 25%, which I *thought* would have worked. I then tried the other options without success. Getting these items into various states of charge to continue experimenting is a bit tedious, so I'm wondering if anyone has successfully automated charging of stuff using AE2.

Note, I have checked my channels, I'm only using 7 (including the chest). The buses are all lit up and operational.

Comment: As far as i know you can also check what items to keep in the chest. You can do this with the same export buses. If you enter the fully charged gear there everything with a different value will get sucked out. I believe i saw Direwolf20 do something similar with his power system.

Comment: That's what I'm hitting now, keeping the stuff that's actually 100% charged _in_ the chest, instead of an endless loop. I'm about at that point where every time I tear it down to try something else I end up making it worse, I hope someone has done this build and knows :)

Comment: I cant double check for you unfortunatly since im currently at work but i believe he covers his method in this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lSUJBfaX7s&list=UU_ViSsVg_3JUDyLS3E2Un5g&index=33 video. He uses ender chests and his power system but i figure it does the same general thing as you want your system to do.

Comment: isn't there a 99% charge option in the fuzzy?

Comment: @ratchetfreak There is an option to split damage at 99%, but that seems to be matching fully charged as well, no matter what state of charge the item I use to program the bus has. Thus, an infinite import / export loop ensues, even though the import buses _only_ pull 100% charged items back into the chest. I now have it working using two chests, but I'm _sure_ there's a way to do it with 1.

Comment: What about using a storage bus partitioned to store only 100% charged versions, a fuzzy import set to split at 99%, and then you should be able to use the one chest for in/out safely without looping? I think. Fuzzy export splitting at 99% should then work connected to the charger and you can use a hopper or something else to an ME interface to pull it back out when charged?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to do this with AE alone (if the export buses don't have a blacklist), but if you have other mods, this should work. You should be able to move the items from the ME chest to a regular chest, or some other storage item (IIRC you can't pull straight from a ME chest). Then you can use thermal dynamics or EnderIO item conduits with a filter blacklist tools full with energy.